# Intl Tel Input Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null at new Iti (intlTelInput.js:146) at intlTelInput.js:1282

Tags: javascript

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/intlTelInput.scss">
<input type="tel" required id="#consultPhone">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/15.0.0/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var consultInput = document.querySelector('#consultPhone');
    var iti = window.intlTelInput(consultInput, {
      separateDialCode:true,
      utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/js/utils.js",
    });
    window.iti = iti;
  </script>
```

So this is my code, when I open the page the input is empty and i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null at new Iti (intlTelInput.js:146 at intlTelInput.js:1282 at index.html:973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I am stupid, forgot to remove the hashtag from the id